# Все русские слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-данных

От куда я могу взять все слова в русском языке? Нужно для собственного т9 на пк.
(желательно все слова с массиве)

Comment: Это невозможно, новые слова появляются постоянно в ходе развития языка, а появляются в словарях годы спустя

Comment: https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/

Answer (score 3):

[здесь](https://github.com/danakt/russian-words) можно взять файл со списком русских слов

Comment: Что прям всех слов? Сомневаюсь :)

Comment: @dIm0n написано, что: Текстовый файл со списком русских слов во всех морфологических формах.
Содержит 1 531 464 записи

Comment: Ну это же не значит, что в русском языке 1 531 464 слов

Comment: @dIm0n Вы правы, нельзя собрать список всех русских слов т.к. язык постоянно развивается в местах страны по разному, и еще вопрос что считать за отдельное слово?

Answer (score 3):

Исключительно в дополнение ответа @timur. Не знаю на сколько вероятно что те словари, ссылки на которые он дал пополняемы (но вдруг). Пара строк кода. Забираем файлы по ссылкам и сохраняем их в `utf-8`:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danakt/russian-words/master/russian.txt')

text = response.content.decode('cp1251')

with open('russian.txt', 'wb') as ru:
    ru.write(text.encode('utf-8'))

response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danakt/russian-words/master/russian_surnames.txt')

text = response.content.decode('cp1251')

with open('russian_surnames.txt', 'wb') as ru:
    ru.write(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 2):

посмотрел я коллекции по ссылкам выше и пришел к выводу что проще сделать свою, получилась более полной (96 тыс слов), отсортированной и удобной (разные котировки и разные форматы). Пользуйтесь: https://github.com/LussRus/Rus_words.git